# Is it possible to make a steam:// desktop shortcut leading to a non-Steam program?

Tags: steam

With any game on Steam, it's possible to make a desktop shortcut for it by pointing it to a location with the `steam://` protocol, like so:

[image: Team Fortress 2 desktop shortcut, pointing to *steam://rungameid/440*]

**However, is it possible to create a shortcut like this for a non-Steam program that is in my Steam library?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible.**

You just need to right click that game

[image: Right Click Menu]

and click "Create Desktop Shortcut"

[image]

and a shortcut will be created on your desktop.

[image: Shortcut Icon]

[image: The shortcut properties]

Comment: Note: It might look a little bit different according to your theme. The theme in the picture is [Metro for Steam](http://metroforsteam.com).